# How to make soap request in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to generate SOAP request in PHP with below SOAP structure:

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://.../CardBalance">
<s:element name="HelloWorld">
<s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="HelloWorldResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HelloWorldResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="SecureLogin">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userProp" type="tns:UserProp"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:SecureLogin"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="UserProp">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="SecureLogin">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="memberID" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cardNumber" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="guid" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="page" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="" name="Population" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="SecureLoginResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SecureLoginResult" type="tns:DTS_Response"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="DTS_Response">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="response_Status" type="tns:Response_Status"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="errorCode" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="errorDescription" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:simpleType name="Response_Status">
<s:restriction base="s:string">
<s:enumeration value="Success"/>
<s:enumeration value="Failure"/>
<s:enumeration value="NotAvailable"/>
<s:enumeration value="GlobalException"/>
</s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
<s:element name="SecureLoginMethod">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userProp" type="tns:UserProp"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:SecureLogin"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="SecureLoginMethodResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SecureLoginMethodResult" type="tns:DTS_Response"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

How can I do that? I tried with:

```
        <?php  
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0); // disabling WSDL cache
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
        $wsdl_path = "https://.../CARDBALANCE/CB_WS.ASMX?WSDL";

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 1));


$res = $client->SecureLogin(array("UserProp"=>array("userName"=>"?","password"=>"?"),"request"=>array("memberID"=>"?","cardNumber"=>"?","guid"=>"?","page"=>1)));

    echo '<br /><br />';

    echo  htmlentities ($client->__getLastRequest());


    try {  
        echo "<pre>\n";  
        var_dump($res->SecureLoginResult);  
        echo "\n</pre>\n";
    }
    catch (SoapFault $exception) {  
        echo $exception;        
    } 

        ?>
```

But I am getting **Fatal Error**:

***Fatal error:*** Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in /var/www/u0109499/data/www/yakosmetolog.ru/soap.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/u0109499/data/www/yakosmetolog.ru/soap.php(48): SoapClient->__call('SecureLogin', Array) #1 /var/www/u0109499/data/www/yakosmetolog.ru/soap.php(48): SoapClient->SecureLogin(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/u0109499/data/www/yakosmetolog.ru/soap.php on line 48

**How can I request that message correctly in PHP? Thanks for any help.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP request by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841288/soap-request-by-php)

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer helps you as well. Generally, the expectation on SO is that you look for similar previous questions and - if they exist - use them or explain why they don't match your situation.

[SOAP request by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841288/soap-request-by-php)